# Eclipse - not changing chormedriver version. It is using old version even if I replace it

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-chromedriver

I have ChromeDriver 93.0.4577.63 downloaded and replaced it in eclipse drivers package. I had previously using 84.0.4147.30. But even after I delete and replace the file, when I run the package, eclipse is using old chromedriver version. I checked task manager and there is no old version of chorme driver running.

[image]

I even tried deleting the whole workspace and recreated it but is is still running old version.

Here is a screenshot of the new version which I checked. This is the file that I copied to eclipse but still it is using old version.

[image]

```
Starting ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}) on port 27261
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84
Build info: version: '3.5.0', revision: '8def36e068', time: '2017-08-10T23:00:22.093Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-asdadsads', ip: '192.168.60.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_301'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x012087E3+2852835]
    Ordinal0 [0x010F5BB1+1727409]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FCE4B9+517305]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F60BA0+68512]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F5D3A0+54176]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F7D9F7+186871]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F7D7FD+186365]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F7B70B+177931]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F62584+75140]
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out..

The chromedriver.exe was cached in c:\Windows\Chromedriver.exe. I replaced the file there and eclipse is using the new version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your driver path. Add below before you create `new ChromeDriver()`

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromeDriver....")
```